# code for OLED display suddenly crashes arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-nano

Today i've been playing with my monochrome oled 128x64 adafruit screen. I've got it connected using SPI. Previously today i had no problems att all and i was able to print messages and variables on the screen. But suddenly my functions causes the arduino Nano to restart and initialise Setup() again!
It is very frustrating and i cannot figure out what part of my code is causing the crash!
I have tried running the adafruit example code to test the screen and it is working, so the screen is not broken and the wires must be correct.

Here is the code for my display: 
display.h :

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>  // Include core graphics library for the display
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>  // Include Adafruit_SSD1306 library to drive the display


#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

// Define SPI pins:

#define OLED_MOSI   9
#define OLED_CLK   6
#define OLED_DC    7
#define OLED_CS    8
#define OLED_RESET 13

// Create display
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
  OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);


#include <Fonts/FreeMonoBold12pt7b.h>  // Add a custom font
#include <Fonts/FreeMono9pt7b.h>  // Add a custom font

void initDisplay(){

  delay(100); 

  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC);

  display.clearDisplay();  // Clear the buffer

  display.setTextColor(WHITE);  // Set color of the text

  display.setRotation(0);  // Set orientation. Goes from 0, 1, 2 or 3

  display.setTextWrap(false);  // By default, long lines of text are set to automatically “wrap” back to the leftmost column.
                               // To override this behavior (so text will run off the right side of the display - useful for
                               // scrolling marquee effects), use setTextWrap(false). The normal wrapping behavior is restored
                               // with setTextWrap(true).

  display.dim(0);  //Set brightness (0 is maximun and 1 is a little dim)

  Serial.println("Display initiated..");

}


void printMessage(String message){
  display.setFont(&FreeMono9pt7b);  // Set a custom font
  display.setTextSize(0);  // Set text size. We are using a custom font so you should always use the text size of 0
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,50);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.print(message);
  display.display();
  Serial.println("printing message on display");
  delay(1000);

}
void printTemp(long temp){

  display.setFont(&FreeMono9pt7b);  // Set a custom font
  display.setTextSize(0);  // Set text size. We are using a custom font so you should always use the text size of 0

  display.clearDisplay();  // Clear the display so we can refresh
  // Print text:
  display.setCursor(25, 15);  // (x,y)
  display.println("temp:");  // Text or value to print
  // Draw rectangle:
  display.drawRect(79, 0, 35, 27, WHITE);  // Draw rectangle (x,y,width,height,color)
                                           // It draws from the location to down-right

  display.setFont(&FreeMonoBold12pt7b);  // Set a custom font
  // Print variable with left alignment:
  display.setCursor(83, 20);  // (x,y)
  display.println(temp);  // Text or value to print

  display.display();  // Print everything we set previously
  Serial.println("Printing temp..");

}
```

main.ino:

```
#include "display.h";
#include "DHT.h";
#include "Radiocom.h";


long temperature;  


void setup() 
{            
  Serial.begin(115200);

  initDHT();
  initDisplay();
  //initRF();
} 


void loop()  
{
  //temperature = readTemp();
  //delay(1000);
  //printTemp(temperature);
  String message = "123456789abc";
  printMessage(message);
  //sendMsg();
  //RFlisten();
  delay(1000);
}
```

If anyone can help me out in any way, i would be really thankfull!

Comment: W/o looking closely at the code, my go to answer for such situations is to make sure your power supply can handle the maximum current demand.  Especially when the display is totally lit up.  Hum, what happens when your code prints nothing (dark screen) to the OLED display?

Comment: Well it was working earlier today and the adafruit example code makes the display work.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying you changed nothing in the code?  And now it is not working?   But the Adafruit example code is working?  Well, other possibilities: 1) You did accidentally change something in your code. 2) You updated the libraries (supporting code) for your platform and changed something.  3) You updated the libraries (supporting code) from Adafruit and changed something.  4) You really are not running your code (uploading it to the Arduino) for some reason. Follow up on these and try to come up w/a few of your own.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Rarely is it the case that the bit you *think* is the problem actually *is* the problem. We need *all* your code.

Comment: Okay i will add the rest of the relevant code

Comment: I edited in the code in the original post

Comment: Well, that String use will be making a mess of your heap - a heap already crowded with the SSD1306 buffer.

Comment: The graphic library, the fonts, the radiocom, the String, it is probably a memory problem. Do you have a arduino mega 2560 or a arduino zero or arduino mkr? When it is not a memory problem then it is still a memory problem but also a power problem.

Comment: Aha! a memory problem seems plausible.. Is there a better way to manage the text than using strings? The program is running on an arduino nano ch340

Comment: When i replace "display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC)" with "  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for(;;);
  }  "
as they use in the adafruit example sketch, i get "SSD1306 allocation failed" in the console.. not sure what causes this

Comment: The arduino does not crash and restart anymore. I stripped away the custom fonts. But it still wont turn the display on or print my message..

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings